# Remover subArray de um Array Principal

Tags: java, array

Possuo dois Arrays principais (`listaInformacoesNota`,`listaInformacoesPedidosPostgreSQL`) com `N` subArrays cada, esses subArrays possuem itens em comum e um item diferente apenas, fiz o seguinte para comparar esses cada subArray:

```
for (List conteudoNotas : listaInformacoesNota){
    for (List conteudoPedidos : listaInformacoesPedidoPostgreSQL){
        if (conteudoNotas.get(3).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(2).toString()) && conteudoNotas.get(4).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(4).toString())){
            if (conteudoNotas.get(1).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(1).toString()) && conteudoNotas.get(2).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(3).toString())){
             \\Aqui eu precisaria remover o subArray (conteudoNotas) do Array principal (listaInformacoesNota)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Minha necessidade é remover do Array principal `listaInformacoesNota` o subArray `condicoesNotas` que se encaixar nas condições, para que ele não seja comparado novamente com nenhum outro subArray.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo dos 2 arrays? Porque o acesso a posições especificas dos arrays dentro dos ifs (`conteudoNotas.get(3)...`) ?

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida? Para remover um item de uma lista basta fazer `lista.remove(item)`, mas você não pode fazer isso enquanto itera a lista em questão. Para fazer isso é necessário utilizar a interface `Iterator`. Você pode ter o iterator necessário através de `listaInformacoesNota.iterator();`. Através do `Iterator` você conseguirá iterar a lista (na verdade, iterar o `Iterator`) e remover o item desejado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover um item da lista, no meio da iteração da mesma, deve-se usar o Iterator.

```
Iterator<List> it = listaInformacoesNota.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    List conteudoNotas = it.next();
    for (List conteudoPedidos : listaInformacoesPedidoPostgreSQL) {
        if (conteudoNotas.get(3).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(2).toString()) && conteudoNotas.get(4).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(4).toString())) {
            if (conteudoNotas.get(1).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(1).toString()) && conteudoNotas.get(2).toString().equals(conteudoPedidos.get(3).toString())) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obs.: eu recomendo fortemente que você crie classes para InformacaoNota e InformacaoPedido e use listas de objetos dessas classes ao invés de lista de listas. Nessas classes você colocaria atributos com nomes significativos para guardar o que seriam esses get(1), get(2), get(3)...

Por exemplo:

```
if (conteudoNota.getOrigem().equals(informacaoPedido.getDestino()) && conteudoNota.getCodigo().equals(informacaoPedido.getCodigo())...
```